# AWAIT / ASYNC example of background worker returning List

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I've seen general examples of how to use AWAIT/ ASYNC with the new 4.5 framework but no specific guidlines on how to replace the use of a background worker with the new constructs that dont in turn call any awaitable methods from the .net framework. how can you do so without using lambda expressions so a List can be returned? I'm thinking somthing like the following to free up the UI if main() is the UI thread (please forgive psudocode)

```
main()
{
      List<string> resultSet = await CreateList(dirPath);
      console.out(resultSet.ToString());
}

public async List<string> CreateList(string dirPath);
{
     //do some work on dirPath NOT CALLING ANY ASYNC methods 
     return LIST<STRING>;
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't even compile. An async method has to return a Tas or Task<List<string>> in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you haven't seen examples of using `async` with synchronous code is because `async` is for *asynchronous* code.

That said, you can use `Task.Run` as an approximate replacement for `BackgroundWorker`. `Task.Run` enables you to take synchronous code and consume it in an asynchronous way:

```
main()
{
  List<string> resultSet = await Task.Run(() => CreateList(dirPath));
  console.out(resultSet.ToString());
}

public List<string> CreateList(string dirPath);
{
  //do some work on dirPath NOT CALLING ANY ASYNC methods 
  return LIST<STRING>;
}
```

I'm currently going through a series on my blog on [replacing `BackgroundWorker` with `Task.Run`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/search/label/Task.Run%20vs%20BackgroundWorker), which you may find helpful.

Comment: Async/await is geared towards truly thread independent asynchronous work. In fact by default async await is single threaded.

Comment: I disagree that "by default async await is single threaded." `async` and `await` are thread agnostic; there is no "default" that can be claimed.

Comment: Ok. More properly async await is a thread agnostic tech. Most implements and set-ups that ship in the framework will not spin up a new thread or use the thread pool (except Task.Factory)